# jQuery custom filter problem: element stack is way too much

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-selectors

I am trying to implement ":random" selector which selects a random element from a stack of elements.

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/nuSWF/

The problem is the selector sometimes tries to select an element which does not exist(out of index). So I prepared the demo code which highlights the cause but I don't understand why. I seems it is a bug or something.

P.S: I know I could select a random element with other methods but this time I have to implement this, also wondering what's going on inside.

Comment: I'm not sure, but isn't `length` always one more than the maximum index? (length = 10 elements last element = 9)

Comment: Also, what values does the index have when it fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing with the stack length is normal, it's just evaluating the `:random` selector on **all** `<a>` elements in `mydiv1` *before* the [`>` child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/), so the length at that point is 4.

For example, this would produce the result you're expecting:

```
var elements2 = $('#mydiv1>a').filter(':random');
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/nuSWF/1/).

---

So what's happening overall is your selector is indeed filtering to random `<a>` elements...but those *may or may not* be further filtered out by the [`>` child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) later (if they're under a `<span>`, they get filtered).  This is true of all selectors if you think about it...any filter you perform just reduces the set of elements...they may further filtered later by more selectors.